# Reseller Domain Registration API for my HTML page JAVA programing

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, jquery

I've currently signed to a service where I can sell domain registration, but I need to integrate there API into my HTML pages, anyone have any idea how to do it, I know to get it in palace above the registration form also the API link is something like https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=111111=0&auth-password=abcxy&domain-name&tlds&suggest-alternative

where, 
My login ID : auth-userid=111111=0
MY password : &auth-password=abcxy
Command parameters :&domain-name&tlds&suggest-alternative

So as I'm not in programing but I have tried implementing it on my site by looking at other domain registration sites source code but to no avail, & I understand that I need some kind of JAVA script with commands like LOAD or GET POST to display the results on my HTML page where I have the MAIN problem, as I have been successful in putting the API link & link it to my SEARCH box, But when even I search for any domain name IT open the above mention API link as https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json? with an ENCRYPTION sign in the URL of the browser but displays as " file not found error " So all I can think as it lacks the script program to display the search result in same or a different page. CAN someone please help me with it. Please I'll be really grateful.

Here's the Form DIV of my HTML :

```
            <div class="domain_finder"><div class="ribbon_large"><img src="images/ribbons/11_large.png" alt="" > </div>
                <form  name="form" id="checkAvailbiltyButton" method="get" action="https://httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=111111=0&auth-password=abcxyz&domain-name=" class="domainsearch">
                    <fieldset>
                    <p><input type="text" id="dsearch" id="RegsiterDomainInput" value="www." class="light" /></p>
                    <p class="avail">Register .com, .co, .net, .org, .us, and more!</p>
                    <label class="print">Search</label>
                    <input type="submit" id="dsubmit" OnClick="doSubmitRegisterDomain();" value="" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to make a server side call. When you just open the url via a form everybody can see the password.

What you need is a server side programming language like:
PHP 
Java (Servlets)

With this you must create a reques, load the url and decode the answer.

Comment: I'm experimenting it on XAMPP & I've updated IP address in reseller a/c to make the API calls,& when I click SEARCH link;URL that opens is https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json? ( & it doesn't display my user id & password ) with an ENCRYPTION next to URL;but comes with an error as FILE NOT FOUND,BUT like I said Something is missing on the page so the JSON update is not displayed & that something might be the JAVA Script which needs to be added where it will just update the search results on my index.html page. Probably a ajax or java script with code LOAD I assume.